# Do not list finalizer tasks in the tasks list

Tags: groovy, gradle

I use Gradle finalizer tasks to clean up some temporary files. Is it possible to hide them from the list of tasks (`gradle tasks`) somehow? They are not intented to be run by the user.

Even though I didn't assign them to any group, they are displayed as *Other tasks* (unlike tasks which some other tasks depend on - they are not displayed).

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Maybe instead of adding a finalizer use a task action?